# Finding the total from a known percentage in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I'm trying to find a Google Sheets formula that will calculate the total amount of a target number if I have a known number which is a known percentage of that number; say I know that 300 is 20% of x. How do I calculate for x?

I know this is not too difficult to calculate mathematically, but how would I write it in a cell formula?

Comment: Google Sheets or Excel? You have both tags attributed to your question. While they have similarities, they are *not* the same thing.

Comment: I'm using Google sheets. Because the complexity of this formula is not very high, my understanding is that that it would be written the same way in Excel as in Google Sheets. An answer that from either world would therefore probably suit my purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If 300 is 20% or ²⁰⁄₁₀₀ or ¹⁄₅ of *x* then multiply 300 by ¹⁰⁰⁄₂₀ or ⁵⁄₁ or 5 to get *x*.

With 300 in A1 and 20% in B1,

```
=A1*(1/B1)
```

Comment: @pnuts -For all intents and purposes, they are both the same formula. I thought the one I posted simply show the reciprocal multiplication a little clearer but the OP should see how to shorten it further from your comment. Thanks!

Comment: That solved it! I've been working on a worksheet that must have fried my brain and just needed this to complete it. That answer appears pretty simple but that helped me out a lot.  Thanks again!